# How to unblock jabber on TI ADSL router with iptables

Tags: router, firewall, iptables, blocking, jabber

I have old but reliable Texas Instruments ADSL router.

> Board AR7RD; BUILD=061005; VERSION=3.7.1 If that matters...

One thing that bothers me is that it somehow blocking my jabber (Pidgin connected to Google account).

I know that the router is causing it, because I tried several different routers and jabber was working with them. I searched through its settings several times, but couldn't find anything that would indicate the blocking.

I managed to get to it using SSH and I figured it must be in iptables settings. Unfortunately I can't read it well, so I'd be greatful for any help.

Here is the original output from iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
CFG        tcp  --  Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
192.168.1.6          anywhere           tcp dpt:www Records Packet's Source Interface 

CFG        tcp  --  Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
192.168.1.6          anywhere           tcp dpt:443 Records Packet's Source Interface 

ACCEPT     tcp  --  Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
0.0.0.0              anywhere           state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
DROP       tcp  --  Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
0.0.0.0              anywhere           state NEW tcp dpt:888 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
0.0.0.0              anywhere           state NEW tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere           tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere           icmp echo-request state NEW 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
192.168.1.150      tcp dpt:ftp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
192.168.1.150      tcp dpt:443 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
Set PR mark for socket 0xf = 230
192.168.1.150      tcp dpt:www 
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere           tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere           icmp destination-unreachable 
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere           state INVALID
```

and here is the same after I cleared it up a bit

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
CFG        tcp  --  192.168.1.6          anywhere           tcp dpt:www Records Packet's Source Interface 
CFG        tcp  --  192.168.1.6          anywhere           tcp dpt:443 Records Packet's Source Interface 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0              anywhere           state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0              anywhere           state NEW tcp dpt:888 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0              anywhere           state NEW tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere           tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere           icmp echo-request state NEW 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.1.150      tcp dpt:ftp 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.1.150      tcp dpt:443 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.1.150      tcp dpt:www 
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere           tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN TCPMSS clamp to PMTU 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere           icmp destination-unreachable 
DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere           state INVALID
```